# How to know the number of frames of a video now in MATLAB without `NumberOfFrames`

Tags: matlab, video-processing

It seems MATLAB is going to delete a `NumberOfFrames` option.

How am I supposed to find out how many frames the video has?

**Example:**

```
Obj       = VideoReader( 'File.avi' );
numFrames = Obj.NumberOfFrames;
```

I've tried to workaround with a `FrameRate*Duration` but if both are not integers it does not work properly some times.

**UPDATE:**

I've submitted a request to Mathworks, let's wait for their response.

Comment: At some point you have to read the video by frame into your workspace, you can either iterate a counter while you're doing this or use `size` on the final data array.

Comment: I have to prealocate arrays for feature selection, so I have to know the number of frames before that.

Comment: I'd suggest [filing a service request](http://mathworks.com/company/aboutus/contact_us/?s_tid=gn_cntus) with The MathWorks to ask about this. Will `NumberOfFrames` be replaced with something else? Why remove it for the sake of a few minor formats that don't support direct determination of the number of frames? Shouldn't `VideoReader` be able to calculate the number faster itself even if it requires more computation (assuming it's not a streaming file)? The `read` method is also tagged to be removed and the new `readFrame` doesn't support indexing in to read a specific frame of a file.

Comment: Why do you needs the NumberOfFrames in the video? If you are doing something like processing entire video one frame at a time and applying an algorithm on each frame, this property is not necessary.

Comment: @DineshIyer did you even read my previous comment?

Comment: @SamuelNLP ... Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a way

```
vid = VideoReader('video.avi');

numframes = int16(fix(vid.FrameRate*vid.Duration));
```

Answer (score 3):

As a non-efficient workaround, you might want to use the [**`hasFrame()`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.hasframe.html) method which is used to know if a frame is available to read. Using it in a while loop, you can pass through the whole video and collect the last counter value as the number of frames...this is not efficient at all but that could work.

**Example:**

```
clc
clear

VideoObj = VideoReader('YourVideo.avi');

NumFrames = 0;
while hasFrame(VideoObj)

%// You can store the current frame into a mov structure. It completely defeats the efficiency since you can't pre-allocate and you are back to original problem though.

    CurrentFrame = readFrame(VideoObj)     
    NumFrames = NumFrames+1;
end
```

Now the number of frames is stored in `NumFrames`.

That's an interesting question!

Comment: thanks for the solution @Benoit_11 that's great to have an answer ( the rest was just a way to help the StackOverflow users grasp your smart trick faster and go get the job done ). Stay tuned, Benoit

Comment: Maybe you were implying this, but I think that you need to call `readFrame` in your loop too in order advance the frame index – at least in R2015a. This of course makes this especially inefficient.

Comment: yes @horchler I was indeed implying it but that was unclear I'll edit the answer thanks for that.